# NSOutlineView Image & Text table cell view unable to assign value

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I have a cell-based NSOutlineView with one "Image & text Table Cell view" in one column. I can assign values to the text-cell via the traditional `NSOutlineViewDelegate` functions just fine, but I can't figure out how to set an image value to the `NSImageCell`.

What I've tried:

- Link the NSImageCell to a referencing outlet (resulted into an error thrown by Xcode);
- Bind the NSImageCell's `objectValue` to a `NSImage` `@property` (results in Xcode deep-frying my CPU while hanging forever on building the storyboard.

It may be a silly thing but what am I not seeing here?

Comment: You either have a cell based outline view (text-cell, NSImageCell) or a view based outline view (Image & text Table Cell view). You can't mix them.

Comment: You sir, have saved the day! I really couldn't find it clear in the Apple documentation. Not to mention that Xcode accepts it but freezes when attempting to build the project.